# Azure Kusto syntax

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I need to run a very simple query

```
requests 
| where cloud_RoleName == "blabla" 
| summarize Count=count() by url
| order by Count desc
```

only thing i need to get the data just from the past 5 minutes
if i  try this :

```
requests | where timestamp < ago(5m)
| where cloud_RoleName == "blabla" 
| summarize Count=count() by url
| order by Count desc
```

or this

```
requests 
| where cloud_RoleName == "blabla" and timestamp < ago(5m)
| summarize Count=count() by url
| order by Count desc
```

but all of them are returning answers with data older than 5 minutes.
ive read the doc and i see no other way of writing this query

can anyone assist?

Comment: Should it be `timestamp > ago(5m)`? I mean if ago(5m) returns the timestamp from 5 minutes ago, you'd want the ones with a timestamp _greater_ than that.

Comment: omg ... yes :o , thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to check if the timestamp is *greater* than the result of `ago()`.
It returns the timestamp from e.g. 5 minutes ago, so if you want the data that is within last 5 minutes, you want the ones with a timestamp higher than that.

So the query should be:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(5m)
| where cloud_RoleName == "blabla" 
| summarize Count=count() by url
| order by Count desc
```